# What's the best way to indicate that the pop up blocker may stop the user from performing a simple task?

Tags: gui-design, popup, browser, help, warnings

I have an application where user have the option to open all selected items in a new windows.

Unfortunately, if the user is running a fancy new-age browser that blocks pop-ups, he doesn’t realize his browser is stopping him from doing it.

By the way, it’s impossible to know if the user have turned it off (or on) the feature in his browser.

Comment: It may be impossible to detect if popup blocker is turned on/off but is it possible for you detect if your new windows opens or not? Maybe something like this [How can I detect if a browser is blocking a popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup) - 
[Detect blocked popup in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome)

Comment: Also are we assuming that the browser or adblocker isn't notifying the user of the blocked popup? Because I think most have that functionality included.

Comment: Do you need to use a window popup at all? Problems like this have led me to do notifications in a page based popup, like an absolutely positioned `div` element, or a jQueryUI dialog. These always work without running into popup blockers, those of today and ones that appear suddenly when a new browser version tightens the rules without warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to notify your users that this is a potential issue with their built-in browser pop-up blockers. For instance, Gmail uses this error message after a new window has failed to open:

> "Grrr! A popup blocker may be preventing the application from opening the page. If you have a popup blocker, try disabling it to open the window."

If you include a message like this, it would also be helpful to include a link to the preferences area of your app/site to disable the option to open selected items in new windows.